# MySQL server migration to GCP SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm migrating from a MySQL server (V 5.5) to Google Cloud (GCP) SQL for MySQL 5.6.  I have the Migration job type setup to Continuous.  The migration completes successfully, however the data is only current to the point when the dump started, it is not syncing the data after the dump as it should.  There are no errors that I can see in the logs.  Hoping for some ideas to try.

Comment: Do you follow any documentation and can you provide any reproducible code?

Comment: I followed all the docs, there was really no code involved, this is an online tool that Google GCP provides.